# Can we add new Datacenter in existing cluster With higher Replication Factor

Tags: cassandra

In Cassandra , to add new Datacenter with higher replication factor in the same cluster throws an error says some range with replication factor 1 is not found in any source Datacenter.

I have Datacenter with (X- RF = 2), and (Y -RF = 1) . I want to add Datacenter (Z - RF = 3).

I have added a nodes in Datacenter Z .
But on

> nodetool rebuild -- X

It Fails with an error

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: unable to find sufficient sources for streaming range (-3685074324747697686,-3680615207285604279] in keyspace with replication factor 1

Basic Details of all Column family :

```
AND bloom_filter_fp_chance = 0.01

AND caching = '{"keys":"ALL", "rows_per_partition":"NONE"}'

AND comment = ''

AND compaction = {'class': 'org.apache.cassandra.db.compaction.SizeTieredCompactionStrategy'}

AND compression = {'sstable_compression': 'org.apache.cassandra.io.compress.LZ4Compressor'}

AND dclocal_read_repair_chance = 0.1

AND default_time_to_live = 0

AND gc_grace_seconds = 864000

AND max_index_interval = 2048

AND memtable_flush_period_in_ms = 0

AND min_index_interval = 128

AND read_repair_chance = 0.0

AND speculative_retry = '99.0PERCENTILE';
```

Comment: Can u post the keyspace? Try 'describe keyspace' incqlsh

Comment: Keyspace have more than 100+ column family . What exactly you want to see .

Below I have shared some common details please have  a look :

Comment: Actually i want the keyspace statement itself. Create keyspace etc.

Comment: I have used very basic query to create keyspace :

 CREATE KEYSPACE keyspace_name WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1 };

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is ALTER KEYSPACE and then nodetool rebuild. Copy the text that you get from DESCRIBE KEYSPACE keyspace_name but without CREATE in the beginning. Add the new datacenter in the replication.

```
ALTER KEYSPACE keyspace_name WITH REPLICATION = { 'class' : 'NetworkTopologyStrategy', 'datacenter1' : 1, 'datacenter2' : 3 };
```

Then do:

```
nodetool rebuild -- datacenter1
```

Comment: What you have said is mentioned in the documentation and following the documentation I had deployed datacenter 2-3 time in production and that works too . But now  when i tried to create another datacenter it gives me the error (ava.lang.IllegalStateException:  ) as i had mentioned on my post. 

My Other datacenter have cassandra version 2.2.9,  Now  the latest cassandra debian package provide  2.2.11 version .

Comment: From your text it looks like you get the error when running "nodetool rebuild -- X". What I mean is that you have to alter the keyspace before doing rebuild.

Comment: I have alter my keyspaces but for the default keyspace like (system_distributed) it throws error .

Answer (score 0):

Your current configuration, as shown in your keyspace definition, is for a *single DC*. You need to ALTER KEYSPACE it - to include another DC into it. This would start the replication process: keys that will be read/written would be replicated to the new DC. To *fully* copy all the data, you would need (in addition) to use the `nodetool rebuild -- DC2` command

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments - 
"I have alter my keyspaces but for the default keyspace like (system_distributed) it throws error"

Other than user specific keyspaces, make sure that default system keyspaces like "system_distributed" are on "NetworkTopologyStrategy" (No keyspaces on SimpleStratergy for multi-DC, except local strategy ) 
Reference: Point-2   https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/3.0/cassandra/operations/opsAddDCToCluster.html

Comment: What you have suggested is true for version 3.0 and later. But I am using version 2.2.X.

Comment: The same applies to 2.2: https://docs.datastax.com/en/cassandra/2.1/cassandra/operations/ops_add_dc_to_cluster_t.html